# Manipulating compound inequalities of supremums and upper bounds

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

$a\in A$, $b\in B$, $\alpha=\sup A$, $\beta=\sup B$, $C=\{a+b:a\in A, b\in B\}$, $\gamma$ is an upperbound for C.

I am trying to show that $\alpha+\beta\le\gamma$ i.e. $\sup C = \sup A + \sup B$.

I have determined that $b\le \beta \le \gamma - a$ and that $a\le \alpha \le \gamma - b$

I combined these inequalities to $a+b \le \alpha + \beta \le 2\gamma - (a+ b)$.

So $2(a+b) \le \alpha + \beta + (a+b) \le 2\gamma$

Clearly $\alpha + \beta + (a+b) \le 2(\alpha + \beta)$, but how do I know that $ 2(\alpha + \beta) \le 2\gamma$? Once I show this I divide by 2 and my proof is done, but I am stuck at this point.

Comment: it is assumed $a \ge 0$ and $b \ge 0$ (not mentioned in question)

Comment: I don't understand how this helps, I am sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us fix an arbitrary $b \in B$. Then for every $a \in A$ we have 
\begin{equation}
a + b \leq \gamma.
\end{equation}
This is true for every $a \in A$. Thus it is also true for $\alpha$ (to see this, choose a sequence of elements in $A$ which converge to $\alpha$.) That is, 
\begin{equation}
\alpha + b \leq \gamma.
\end{equation} 
Now, this inequality holds for every $b \in B$ and thus it also holds for $\beta$.